# How to get user posts using Firebase and Authenticate Using Facebook?

Tags: javascript, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase auth to login via facebook. I want to get some extra data from the facebook account(posts and education). 
I learned information that I have to use Graph API - **graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{person-id}**, but I can't find how get '*person-id*' if the user has been logged via Firebase auth(auth.currentUser).

Comment: You’re probably looking for something similar to this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50442344/1427878

Answer (score 1):

You can get back all the Facebook user info after sign-in regardless which method you use to sign in:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCred)
  .then((result) => {
    // All facebook additional user info available here:
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.profile);
  });

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(facebookProvider)
  .then((result) => {
    // All facebook additional user info available here:
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.profile);
  });
```